# Parsing malformed json string which doesn't have double quotes around it (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, json, malformed

```
{ ValidationError: { device_uuid: [ [Object] ] } }
```

I like to convert this string to JSON format which will be like

```
{ "ValidationError": { "device_uuid": [ [Object] ] } }
```

Is there anyway that I can possibly get this result from malformed JSON string?

Comment: Where do you got the string from? Why doesn't it have quotation marks around the keys in the first place? What's the purpose of this string?

Comment: First rule of programming: Never try to work with faulty input and guess what could have been ment. Throw a plain error instead!

Comment: I wrote a parser to handle this exact situation, along with several others. I'm not sure if your specific JSON will work with that I wrote, but you can give it a try [here](http://rmarcus.info/dirty-json/).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're sure that the improperly formatted string is safe and is just malformed JSON (ie not going to execute any other javascript), you could just eval and then JSON.stringify it.

`JSON.stringify(eval('(' + myString + ')'));`

Comment: `JSON.stringify(eval("{ ValidationError: { device_uuid: 'Object' } }"));` yields `'"Object"'`for me...

Comment: It should be `eval('(' + myString + ')')`. `{ValidationError: ...}` is not valid JavaScript on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

I've found really cool javascript library.
https://github.com/freethenation/durable-json-lint

It helped my malformed json string to wellformed json string!

```
durableJsonLint = require('durable-json-lint');
console.log(durableJsonLint('{name:"value", \'array\':[call(), 0x11]}'))
// The above code would print the following to the console
{
   "json":'{"name":"value", "array":[null, 17]}',
   "errors":[{
         "column":1,
         "description":"Keys must be double quoted in Json. Did you mean \"name\"?",
         "lineNumber":1,
         "status":"correctable"
      },{
         "column":15,
         "description":"Json strings must use double quotes",
         "lineNumber":1,
         "status":"correctable"
      },{
         "column":24,
         "description":"You can not make function calls in Json. Do you think I am a fool?",
         "lineNumber":1,
         "status":"fail"
      },{
         "column":32,
         "description":"Invalid Json number",
         "lineNumber":1,
         "status":"correctable"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I've also written a library to handle a few more cases: https://github.com/RyanMarcus/dirty-json